# C#, SignalR, Owin self host - I'm not able to unsucribe events

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, owin

First, I'm sorry for me English.
I try to write a code for RFID reader and I would like to use C# + SignalR + Owin.
I have following code.

```
namespace SignalRSelfHost {
   using System;
   using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
   using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
   using Owin;
   using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
   using ReaderSDK;


   class Program{
      static void Main(string[] args) {
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:8080/")) {
            Console.WriteLine("Server running at http://localhost:8080/");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
      }
   }

   public class Startup {
      public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
         app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
         app.MapSignalR();
      }
   }

   //class for basic reader settings with reader event + event handler
   public class RFIDReader {
      public Reader reader = new Reader();
      //definition event, what I'll fire for MyHub class
      public event Action<string> TagToClient;

      public RFIDReader() {
         try {
            //connect to reader
            reader.Connect("xx.xx.xx.xx");
            // event from reader and handler
            reader.TagsComing += TagsComingHandler;
         }
         catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
         }
      }

      //handler for event readerTagsComming  
      void TagsComingHandler(Reader sender, Tags packet) {
         foreach (Tag tag in packet) {
           //fire event for MyHub class
           TagToClient(tag.toString());
         }
      }
   }

   //MyHub class for communication via SignalR
   public class MyHub : Hub {
      static RFIDReader rfidreader = new RFIDReader();

      // this method is activated from JavaScript client of course
      // JavaScript client code is not relevant for this example 
      public void ReaderStart() {
        //start of reader reads
        rfidreader.start();
        //here I want unsucribe handler - it doesn't works
        rfidreader.TagToClient -= TagToClientHandler;
        //here I subcribe handler
        rfidreader.TagToClient += TagToClientHandler;      
      } 


      //handler for event TagToClient
      void TagToClientHandler(string tagNumber){
         Console.WriteLine(tagNumber);
      }


      //this method is also activated from JavaScript client
      public void ReaderStop() {
         //stop of readers reads
         rfidreader.stop();
      }

   }

}
```

My problem is, that I'm not able unsucribe event handler TagToClientHandler and if I repeatedly perform method ReaderStart in MyHub class, I get a data from reader twice, thrice, etc..
I have there unsubscribing of this handler, however, it has no effect.
Does somebody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
static void TagToClientHandler(string tagNumber){
    Console.WriteLine(tagNumber);
}
```

define void TagToClientHandler as static should do the trick, else probably everytime the handler has another reference and -= won't remove anything

or just set TagToClient to null

```
rfidreader.TagToClient = null
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, however it doesn't works.                     TagToClientHandler can't be static (there is continuity on non-static SignalR method Clients.All.AnyClientFunction(tagNumber), which I forgot to write into illustratice code)  and rfidreader.TagToClient = null doesn't works too, because compiller returns exception  "The event 'Speedway.TagToClient' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= "

Answer (score 0):

Hub instances are transient and you will get a new instance for each request. As a result storing any kind of data that is supposed to be used across multiple calls or subscribing to events is not going to work. You need to have a separate way for storing things whose lifetime is longer than the lifetime of the Hub but still accessible from the Hub so that you can invoke methods from your hub (the simplest thing might be just a static property on the hub but you need to think if it will work if you have multiple clients and they all will start invoking methods (also think about threading)).

Note that the Hub class has OnConnected/OnDisconnected events that can also be useful in your case to track connections.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your static initializer

```
static RFIDReader rfidreader = new RFIDReader();
```

Since MyHub is transient, a new one is instantiated on every call.  That means you are reinitializing rfidreader on every call.  You should add a constructor to the class, check for null and only initialize it if null

```
public class MyHub : Hub {
   static RFIDReader rfidreader = null;

   public MyHub() {
      if (rfidreader == null) {
         rfidreader = new rfidreader();
   }

...
}
```